# Locate the Keys with same values in JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have below json

```
[{
    "workType": "NDB To Nice",
    "priority": 5
},
{
    "workType": "PDAD",
    "priority": 0
}, {
    "workType": "PPACA",
    "priority": 0
}, {
    "workType": "Retrigger",
    "priority": "5"
}, {
    "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake",
    "priority": "7"
}]
```

I need to call out all the "worktype" which have same "priority" , iff the priority is NOT EQUAL TO 0.

Means for above example i should get keys = ["NDB To Nice","Retrigger"] since they both have priority 5.

I have tried below code

```
  function(array, k) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    (acc[cur[k]] = acc[cur[k]] || []).push(cur);
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

But i am not able to achieve the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [{ "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5 }, { "workType": "PDAD", "priority": 0 }, { "workType": "PPACA", "priority": 0 }, { "workType": "Retrigger", "priority": "5" }, { "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake", "priority": "7" }];
const output = array.filter(a => a.priority > 0 && array.filter(a2=> a.priority == a2.priority).length > 1).map(a => a.workType);
console.log(output)
```

Comment: oh, i didn't think about filtering the same array within itself. That looks the possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```js
var input = [{ "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5 }, { "workType": "PDAD", "priority": 0 }, { "workType": "PPACA", "priority": 0 }, { "workType": "Retrigger", "priority": "5" }, { "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake", "priority": "7" }];

var output = input.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.priority] = r[a.priority] || [];
  if (!r[a.priority].includes(a.workType)) {       // <-- ignore duplicates
    r[a.priority].push(a.workType);
  }
  return r;
}, Object.create(null));
  
console.log(output);        // <-- all priorities
console.log(output['5']);   // <-- priority '5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to group items by `reduce` method and then just `filter`

```
let hashMap = input.reduce((a, {workType, priority})=> {
    if (priority > 0) {
       a[priority] = a[priority] || [];
       a[priority].push(workType);
    }
    return a;
},{});
let result = Object.entries(hashMap)
   .filter(([k, v]) => v.length > 1)
   .map(([k, v]) => v);
```

An example:

```js
let input = [{ "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5 },
{ "workType": "PDAD", "priority": 0 },
{ "workType": "PPACA", "priority": 0 },
{ "workType": "Retrigger", "priority": "5" },
{ "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake", "priority": "7" }
];

// I need to call out all the "worktype" which have same "priority" , if the priority is NOT EQUAL TO 0.
// keys = ["NDB To Nice","Retrigger"]
let hashMap = input.reduce((a, {workType, priority})=> {
  if (priority > 0) {
  a[priority] = a[priority] || [];
  a[priority].push(workType);
  }
  return a;
},{});
let result = Object.entries(hashMap).filter(([k, v]) => v.length > 1).map(([k, v]) => v);
console.log(result);
```

Or of you like inline methods (in my view, it lacks readablitity)

```js
let input = [{ "workType": "NDB To Nice", "priority": 5 },
{ "workType": "PDAD", "priority": 0 },
{ "workType": "PPACA", "priority": 0 },
{ "workType": "Retrigger", "priority": "5" },
{ "workType": "Special Intake Request Intake", "priority": "7" }
];

let hashMap = input.reduce((a, {workType, priority})=> ( ((priority > 0) ? 
(a[priority] = a[priority] || [], a[priority].push(workType)) : null), a), {});
let result = Object.entries(hashMap).filter(([k, v]) => v.length > 1).map(([k, v]) => v)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is grouping the non zero keys.

Comment: Also , the priority can be different than 5 as well

Comment: @Rishabh I am sorry, I was in hurry. I am a little bit late at the party, but I've edited the code. Please, see my updated solution.

Comment: Thanks  a lot sir.